# How to write generic query executor method for delete?

Tags: slick, slick-2.0

I'm trying to write a generic query executor method. It works fine for `insert`, `update`, `getList`. For `delete` code did not compile. Is there any way do this?

```scala
import scala.slick.driver.JdbcProfile

trait DBComponent {

  val profile: JdbcProfile

  import profile.simple._

  def dbObject(): Database
}

trait QueryExecutor { this: DBComponent =>

  import profile.simple._

  def execute[T <: Rep[_], F, C[_]](query: Query[T, F, C]): List[F] =    dbObject.withSession { implicit session: Session => query.list }

  def executeUpdate[T <: Rep[_], F, C[_]](query: Query[T, F, C], value: F): Int = dbObject.withSession { implicit session: Session => query.update(value) }

  def executeInsert[T <: Rep[_], F, C[_]](query: Query[T, F, C], value: F): Int = dbObject.withSession { implicit session: Session => query.insert(value) }

  def executeDelete[T <: Rep[_], F, C[_]](query: Query[T, F, C]): Int = dbObject.withSession { implicit session: Session => query.delete }*/
  //getting error => delete is not a member of QueryExecutor.this.profile.simple.Query[T,F,C]
}
```

Comment: try `queryToDeleteInvoker(query).delete`. What happens with that?

Comment: thanks @cvogt , it did not work.Getting compilation error:
  
 found   : QueryExecutor.this.profile.simple.Query[T,F,C]
[error]     (which expands to)  scala.slick.lifted.Query[T,F,C]
[error]  required: scala.slick.lifted.Query[QueryExecutor.this.profile.Table[_], _, ?]

Comment: Can't see why right now, added a ticket https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1040

Comment: @cvogt thanks for creating ticket.